# apache camel route testing

Tags: spring-boot, junit, apache-camel

I have written a test case for an apache camel route below,

I believe this only tests message transfer from SEDA send endpoint to mock endpoint, but may not test prism camel route. want to see if how to mock the actual endpoint - if possible.

```java
package com.sams;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit5.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import com.sams.pricing.prism.data.processor.util.Endpoints;

public class CamelRouteTests extends CamelTestSupport {

    
    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from(Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT)
                    .to("mock:" +  Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT);
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testRoute() throws Exception {
        // Set up the expectations for the mock endpoint
        getMockEndpoint("mock:" + Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT).expectedMessageCount(1);

        // Send a message to the seda:sendMessage endpoint
        template.sendBody("seda:sendMessage", "test message");

        // Verify that the mock endpoint expectations are met
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }



}
```

```java
// SEDA Endpoint Stage Event Driven Architecture
    from(Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT)
        .messageHistory()
        // Route Name
        .routeId(Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT)
        .log("${body}")

        // multicast
        .multicast()
        .parallelProcessing() // create parellel threads
        .log("${body}")

        // thread pool
        .threads()
        .executorService(executorService) // specific thread pool
        .log("Camel Route Started Message Processing : - ${body}")

        // content based routing
        .choice()
        .when(
            CommonUtility
                .costIQPredicate) // predicate checking based on the header value to decide the
        // route
     //    .bean(CostIQService.class, "calculatePrice") // // rules engine call
        .bean(CostIQPayloadTransformer.class, "payloadTransformer") // payload transformer

        // multiple consumer
        .to(
            Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT, // consumer 1
            Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT, // consumer 2
            Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT) // consumer 3
        .when(CommonUtility.optimizationPredicate)
        .bean(OptimizationService.class, "calculatePrice")
        .bean(CostIQPayloadTransformer.class, "payloadTransformer")
        .to(
            Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT,
            Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT,
            Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT)
        .when(CommonUtility.markDownPredicate)
        .bean(MarkDownService.class, "calculatePrice")
        .bean(CostIQPayloadTransformer.class, "payloadTransformer")
        .to(
            Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT,
            Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT,
            Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT)
        .when(CommonUtility.pricingPredicate)
        .bean(PricingService.class, "calculatePrice")
        .bean(CostIQPayloadTransformer.class, "payloadTransformer")
        .to(
            Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT,
            Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT,
            Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT)
        .log("Final :- ${body}")
        .end();
  }
```

Where SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT = "seda:sendMessage?blockWhenFull=true&concurrentConsumers=100"

and SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT = "seda:processMessage?blockWhenFull=true"

Have tried to look up mocking but could not find a solution as that would not test the actual camel route.

Update - have tried to use the AdviceWith method as described but am getting an error

```
AdviceWith.adviceWith(context, Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT, a -> {
        a.mockEndpoints(Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT);
    });
```

am getting this error below

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot advice route as there are
> no routes     at
> org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWith.findRouteDefinition(AdviceWith.java:262)
> at org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWith.adviceWith(AdviceWith.java:74)
> at
> com.sams.pricing.prism.data.processor.CamelRouteTests1.testRoute(CamelRouteTests1.java:26)
> at java.base/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to override `createRouteBuilder()` in your Test class. But in your test, you do need to tell Camel to mock the endpoints you're interested in:

```java
AdviceWith.adviceWith(context, Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT, a -> {
    a.mockEndpoints(Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT));
});
```

Then. you could do

```java
getMockEndpoint("mock:" + Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT)...
```

See this about [mocking existing endpoints](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/mock-component.html#_mocking_existing_endpoints).

Comment: getMockEndpoint("mock:direct:start").expectedBodiesReceived("Hello World");
      
        template.sendBody("direct:start", "Hello World");

in the example that the link provides what would I replace "direct:start" with? my endpoint?

there are 2 endpoints, would I not use the SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT?

Comment: It might make more sense to mock SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT. It just depends on what you're wanting to test. I updated my answer with more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the update! - assuming when I do the sendBody I would do something like         template.sendBody(Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT, "test message");?

Comment: Updated the question - am getting an issue using the AdviceWith